# correct way to return variables as arguments to method

Tags: python

A noob confused question,

I have two methods in a class as :

```
from example import sample2
class sample1:
      def m1():
           a='apple'
           b='ball'
           return sample2.m3(a,b)
      def m2():
           a='ant'
           b='bat'
           c='cat'
           return sample2.m3(a,b,c)
```

in example.py:

```
class sample2:
       def m3("here I want to access any `a`,`b`,`c` of respective m1 and m2"):
            .....
```

Iam sorry if this question makes no sense, but when I try to access only this as:

```
class sample1:
      def m1():
           a='apple'
           b='ball'
           return sample2.m3(a,b)
```

in example.py:

```
 class sample2:
       def m3(a,b):
           print(a)
```

`a` has value `apple`, so similar way why can't I access any value of a,b,c from that particular `m1`,`m2` returned ?

Comment: Note that the *variable* ``a`` in ``m1`` is distinct from the ones in ``m2`` in ``m2`` even if they hold the same value. Even if you pass ``m1:a`` to ``m2:a`` you are just exchanging the value, not the variables.

Comment: sorry it is return sample2.m3(a,b) I have edited

Comment: So you want to change the values of a, b and c in the function m3?

Comment: @MohammadElAssal not change, but i want to access a='ant' in m3 but `a` have two values 'apple' and 'ant' both returned from `m2`and `m1`

Comment: I think that you do not need classes for your tasks. What makes you struggle is probably type of methods (which require 'self' object with class instance as first argument). If you use decorator ```@staticmethod``` before each method definition, you should probably be able to execute your code. It literally make every single method work as casual function.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. When you call sample2.m3 you are already passing the variables a, b (and c), so just define m3 with optional a,b and c input variables.

Comment: Those are different a's. You are not accessing the same a.

Comment: @MaciejD Exactly sir, I guess I have to proceed as you mentioned, but can you post an answer for my requirement in question?....I understood the concept but have no idea to implement, appreciate if you do it

Comment: Sure, will do in a second.

Comment: Instead of making every "method" a staticmethod, simply remove the useless classes around them. Note that neither approach will change how variables behave.

Comment: @Sophie I have added an anwer. It should help you out.

Comment: @MaciejD Thanks, I would go through that

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Python always apply to a specific *scope*, such as a class, function or closure. Python uses [lexical scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope), which means scopes are only connected by nesting in the source code. Most importantly, variables in *different* scopes are not connected at all.

When you "pass a variable" to a function, you are actually passing only the value around. The variable does not exist in other functions (unless they are nested) nor the surrounding scope.

```
def nested(a):
    a = 3
    print('a =', a)  # a = 3

def parent():
    a = 4
    nested(a)
    print('a =', a)  # a = 4

parent()
print(a)  # NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Functions should primarily exchange data by calling with input and `return`ing results:

```
def nested(a):       # receive input
    a = 3
    print('a =', a)  # a = 3
    return a         # return output

def parent():
    a = 4
    a = nested(a)    # replace a with result of nested(a)
    print('a =', a)  # a = 3

parent()
```

Note that only values are passed in and returned. The above could would behave exactly the same if you renamed `a` in either function.

---

When working with class *instances*, the instance itself works as a namespace (similar to a scope). Methods *of that instance* can exchange data by modifying attributes of the instance. The instance is always passed as the first argument to methods:

```
class Example():
    """An example for setting attributes on an instance"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    def nested(self):
        self.a = 3
        print('self.a =', self.a)  # self.a = 3

    def parent(self):
        self.a = 4
        print('self.a =', self.a)  # self.a = 4
        self._nested()
        print('self.a =', self.a)  # self.a = 3

instance = Example()
print(instance.a)  # 0
instance.parent()  # self.a = 4
                   # self.a = 3
```

To exchange data *between* objects, methods should also primarily exchange data by calling with input and `return`ing results :

```
class Example():
    """An example for setting attributes on an instance"""
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def multiply(self, value):
        return self.a * value

instance = Example(6)
print(instance.multiply(10))  # 60
```

Comment: For completeness, maybe you can introduce optional variables in your answer. Since the op is calling `sample2.m3` with different number of parameters, she will have to use at least `c` as optional, or just use *args

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I'm not sure if that is what the OP struggles to understand - it would be a needless complication if not.

Comment: this is simply understandable, but I want to pass them as arguments to another method !!

Comment: @Sophie Passing parameters to functions, methods of the same class or methods of another class works the same. It is literally the same mechanism.

Comment: May i know how to approach that with an example?

Comment: @Sophie The answer already contains an example of calling methods with arguments. What additional example do you need?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use decorators. More information how decorator works can be found in for example here: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/decorators-python

I would suggest you to first try to better understand concept of class and objects. Example tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

This post could also help you to understand how staticmethod decorator works - [What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod)

```
from example import sample2

class sample1:
    @staticmethod
    def m1():
        a='apple'
        b='ball'
        return sample2.m3(a,b)

    @staticmethod
    def m2():
        a='ant'
        b='bat'
        c='cat'
        return sample2.m3(a,b,c)
```

example.py file with explanation:

```
class sample2:
    @staticmethod
    def m3(a, b, c=None): # it works exactly the same as m3 function that is outside the class
        print(a)
        # this can be used without creating an object of sample2 class, example:
        # sample2.m3(a="apple, b="ball")

    def m3_method(self, a, b): # this one requires object on which it can be called
        print(a)
        # you have access to sample2 class object via self parameter, example of code:
        # sample2_object = sample2() # you create object of sample2 class here
        # sample2_object.m3_method(a="apple", b="ball") # you call m3_method on sample2_object here


def m3(a, b, c=None): # default value of c is add so you can either call it with 2 or 3 arguments
    # example calls:
    # m3("a", "b")
    # m3("a", "b", "c")
    print(a)
```

You should be able to run this code and I think it gives you an idea how Python classes can be used.

Comment: so, in sample2 m3, can't we access any like:  def m3(any of a,b,c)  as we are returning same `a` with different values and there may not be any overriding too I guess

Comment: oh, I have not notices that you might want to use 2 or 3 parameters. There is also wasy to do that. Let me do the edit.
Look at m3 function definition - there is python way of  function 'overloading'. So it can be either called with 3 or 2 parameters (if argument is not given, it will have default value - None in this case).

Comment: i'm expecting like accessing a='ant' and a='apple' any when required ....could that be possible?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't think I understand what you are trying to say. I have fixed the syntax error that you have been struggling with, but I need more detail about what you are trying to achieve to help you more. If you could describe step by step what is the entry point and what you are trying to achieve, then I would probably be able to help you with code rework.

Comment: as you mentioned method overloading, if there is some method like m1 say m4 and have different values for `a`,`b` then printing `a` would give me?? ...@staticmethod
    def m4():
        a='aqua'
        b='bill'
        return sample2.m3(a,b)